# Adding values to referential entity using REST API POST

Tags: 8, nodes

I have 2 custom content type. One is movies and the other is actors. I am using REST API POST to add values into movies. Actor is a referential entity within movies. How do I add values into actors which are corresponding to a particular movie when I use POST?

An option that I am currently trying out is add multiple values into actors first and that POST will return a node id, use that node id value along POST values to movies. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the article about create [Custom Rest Resources for POST](https://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-custom-rest-resources-for-post-methods-drupal-8)

You can reference below code below

```
$node_actor = Node::create(
      ['type' => 'actor',// the content type
        'title' => 'Actor Name',
      ]
    );
   $actor_id = $node_actor->save();
```

After you can use `$actor_id` had node reference to movie

```
$node_movie = Node::create(
   ['type' => 'movie',// the content type
    'title' => 'Movie Name',
   ]
  );
  $node_movie->set('field_actor_ref',['target_id'=>$actor_id])
  $node_movie->save();
```